# Parsing a directory in a string to ofstream file.open

Tags: c++, windows, fstream, iostream

I am trying to parse a directory through the command line and open the file based on what is put in. The command line argument seems to be correct as I print it just before to make sure, but the location file doesn't seem to get modified.

If I pass the string: A:/Documents/fstreamtest/test.txt (location of the .txt and cpp files) the file will remain unchanged

If I pass the string: test.txt it seems to work

I have tried with '/' as well as '\\' for the different directories.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    string str;
    string fileName;
    ofstream file;


    if(argc>=2){
        fileName = argv[1];
        cout << fileName.c_str() << endl;
        file.open(fileName.c_str());
    } else{
        file.open("wordlist.txt");
    }

    cout << "Enter a value..." << endl;
    cin >> str;

    file << "test\n" << "\n";
    vector<char> cha(str.c_str(), str.c_str() + str.size() + 1);

    for(int i = 0; cha[i]!='\0'; i++){
        cout << cha[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `/` or a backslash has to do with your OS.. Are you on Windows, or a UNIX-like system (e.g. Ubuntu, Mac), etc.? Also, what do you mean by `A:/Documents/.../test.txt`? Include in your question exactly what you are passing as the cmd arguments. Moreover, indent your code, and probably complete your main function..

Comment: I'm on windows, so either should work. The: A:/Documents/.../test.txt is the location of the .txt file I'm trying to access without the folders in between I have just cut down the amount of folders in between for readability. Again the main function is complete, and indented correctly (I assume it didn't copy over correctly which is on me - My first post), I have just only included the part of the function that is responsible for opening the file for less clutter.

Comment: On Windows I believe you have to do a quadruple backslash `\\\\A:\\Documents\\fstreamtest\\test.txt` since you are starting at the root directory.